# How to fix OAuthManager authorize call on android device?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am writing my first react-native application and trying to get fullstackreact/react-native-oauth facebook login to work. It works ok and login succeeds on android emulator but when run on device a small all white dialog appears and `manager.authorize('facebook')` method never resolves.

code:

```
login_facebook() {
const config = {
  facebook: {
    client_id: '****',
    client_secret: '****'
  }
}
const manager = new OAuthManager('***dev');
manager.configure(config);

console.log('one');
manager.authorize('facebook')
       .then(data => {
          console.log('two');
          console.log(data);
       })
       .catch(err => {
          console.log('three');
          console.log(err)
       });
```

}

adb -s device_id logcat | grep -E 'ReactNativeJS|OAuthManager':

```
I/OAuthManager(28552): configureProvider for facebook
I/ReactNativeJS(28552): one
```

Any ideas what might be the problem or how to debug it further?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by...

On the https://developers.facebook.com/ site.
On the "Facebook Login" tab and in the the "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" list,

I added "http://localhost/facebook" and I immediately started receiving the redirect.

I didn't need to do anything like this for iOS on the developers.facebook.com  site.